# Adding a set of buttons to ListView and then setting adapter and setting button texts

Tags: android, button, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

Hi guys I'm having difficulty figuring out why my buttons wont display the right text and display junk code. I am running a serverRequest then creating the buttons after the details are gotten and I surely did test I am getting the right string back from the server.

```
public void getCourses(User user) {
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
    serverRequest.fetchUserCoursesDataInBackground(user, new getUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doneString(String[] returnedString) {
            if (returnedString == null) {
                System.out.println("DONE EMPTY");
            } else {
                userLocalStore.storeUserCourses(returnedString);
                final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewCourseList);
                final ArrayList<Button> list = new ArrayList<>();
                View v = getWindow().getDecorView();

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedString.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("This is in for loop:" +returnedString[i]);
                    Button button = new Button(v.getContext());
                    button.setText(returnedString[i]);
                    button.setId(i);
                    button.setHeight(40);
                    button.setWidth(100);
                    list.add(button);
                }
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("List is empty bro");
                } else {
                    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    System.out.println("Adding adapter");
                }
            }
        }
```

this is the whole code. I will show you what it is displaying on the application

[this is the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TptN.jpg)

Comment: Did you try putting a hardcoded string in? button.settext("foobar");

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything  Just tried it. Didn't make a difference same thing.

Comment: Could it be that you are using the wrong context?

Comment: Maybe pass the context from the fragment or activity from where you are calling getCourses

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything No it didn't work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 problems in this code:

1st i assume java can mess this 1 up:

replace> final ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

with> final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

2nd you are using a layout "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" for the ArrayAdapter which is an xml layout including a text view thus you screenshot shows 2 text views and not buttons.

3rd new ArrayAdapter() constructor takes a list of Strings. so if you...

replace> final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

with> final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, returnedString);

you will see buttons with the text that you are printing in your loop.